# How get a list variable from tkinter OptionMenu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to get the list variable from an `OptionMenu` tkinter widget in python3.3.

The widget is written like this;

```
list1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three']
var1 = tkinter.StringVar()
var1.set(list1[0])

window = tkinter.Tk()
my_opmenu = tkinter.OptionMenu(window, var1, *list1)
my_opmenu.grid()
window.mainloop()
```

I know you can use the `cget()` method to retrieve the config of a widget, and I think in the context of the `OptionMenu` widget `my_opmenu` is the setting I need to call. But when I call it I get something that looks like a memory location.

```
print(my_opmenu.cget('menu'))
>>.24620080.24620272.25126224.25126352.25126736.menu
```

Obviously the memory location is not constant. Is there any way I can get a human value returned (i.e. `list1`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get the list variable because the widget knows nothing about the list variable. When you create the widget you are providing *values* from the list widget, but not the list itself.

The `menu` attribute returns an instance of a `Menu` class. It won't know anything about your list, either.

If you want to associate the list with the widget, set it as an attribute:

```
my_opmenu.list = list1
```

Later, when you want the list back you can do something like:

```
print "my list:", my_opmenu.list
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do you then fetch the attribute? If I perform the above association, then `my_opmenu.cget('list')` returns an error.

Comment: @I_do_python: you use `my_opmenu.list`.